# Hard Disk Formatting Error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, ext4

so here is the situation..

I installed Ubuntu, pretty sweet.... all was going well till i tried to install an application " LPCXpresso IDE for ARM micro controllers" now the PC hung up as soon as the installation started and after 10 minutes i shut off the PC (pulled the power cord).
now when i boot.. i cant get past the boot loader.. i mean if i select my Ubuntu installation on the boot loader prompt i just reboot...
now i tried to reinstall Ubuntu... using the same hard disk partition that i used before.. got some kind of an error (i tried installing from a USB stick)..
now i am running Ubuntu from my USB stick and trying to install it on the same 15GB partition.. i deleted the partition and then created it again but when i create the partition i get this error

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
ext2fs_check_if_mount: Input/output error while determining whether /dev/sda3 is mounted.
mkfs.ext4: Input/output error 
    while trying to create journal

Filesystem label=New Volume
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
952848 inodes, 3807405 blocks
190370 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=3900702720
117 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8144 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208

Writing inode tables:   0/117  1/117  2/117  3/117  4/117  5/117  6/117  7/117  8/117  9/117 10/117 11/117 12/117 13/117 14/117 15/117 16/117 17/117 18/117 19/117 20/117 21/117 22/117 23/117 24/117 25/117 26/117 27/117 28/117 29/117 30/117 31/117 32/117 33/117 34/117 35/117 36/117 37/117 38/117 39/117 40/117 41/117 42/117 43/117 44/117 45/117 46/117 47/117 48/117 49/117 50/117 51/117 52/117 53/117 54/117 55/117 56/117 57/117 58/117 59/117 60/117 61/117 62/117 63/117 64/117 65/117 66/117 67/117 68/117 69/117 70/117 71/117 72/117 73/117 74/117 75/117 76/117 77/117 78/117 79/117 80/117 81/117 82/117 83/117 84/117 85/117 86/117 87/117 88/117 89/117 90/117 91/117 92/117 93/117 94/117 95/117 96/117 97/117 98/117 99/117100/117101/117102/117103/117104/117105/117106/117107/117108/117109/117110/117111/117112/117113/117114/117115/117116/117done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks):
```

earlier I ended up with 1.2 or 1.5 MB ext4 Partitions when i tried this....

I'm new to Linux but i am aware of certain Linux fundamentals.. so it would be great if the answer is presented accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `dmesg` for more detailed errors, and check the drive's SMART status in the disk utilty.  Most likely it's a dead/dieing drive, though a cable or controller problem is another possibility.